# stretching a cell when using singularitygs

Tags: stretch, flexbox, singularitygs

Just a newbie getting into web development.

I have been going through many grid systems and I really like the concept behind singularitygs.  It's very unique.

I have not tried Singularitygs yet but I wanted to ask about this one problem that I am running into with other grid systems.

It is the problem of stretching nested cells so that the top and the bottoms line up within a container.

CSS3 offers flexbox with stretch option but it is not supported by IE8 or 9.

Does singularitygs offer any solution to this formatting problem? How would I go about lining up the cells without having to fall back on CSS table layout when I am using singularitygs?

Thank you.

Comment: Show us some code please.

Comment: The table display properties *are* the fallback if what you want are adjacent elements that stretch.

Comment: Yes, table display will work except I have not found a grid system that has an option to output columns in a CSS table display.  Most gs seems to use float left and then float right for omega.

Answer (score 0):

It does not out of the box, no, but you can customize output methods to output `display: table` and `display: table-cell`. Unfortunately the output API is [not well documented](https://github.com/Team-Sass/Singularity/wiki/Output-API).

Comment: Even if output is in table method, I would assume one would still have to go back to HTML to add additional containers for the table format layout.  It's such a pain to line up the bottom. A flexbox with align:end is a perfect solution but IE is screwing that up.

Comment: Decided to just write a js function to handle the situation.  Thank you.